# JS works on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have this form that delete an entry and when its clicked its gonna give an alert box

This is the HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" style="display:inline;" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/1" method="POST">
    <input class="hidden" type="submit" value="Delete"></input>
    <a class="m-l-sm js-delete-confirm" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this entry ??" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-times fa-hover" title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"></i>
    </a>
</form>
```

This is the JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-delete-confirm', function() {
    console.log('clicked delete');
    event.preventDefault();
    var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));
    if (choice) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit()
    }
});
```

This works on Google Chrome, but not in Firefox.
Any idea what did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors do you get when you run this in firefox? What version of firefox does the error occur in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, but the missing `event` parameter on your click handler might be throwing an error in firefox:

```
// Add event parameter to anonymous click function
$(document).on('click', '.js-delete-confirm', function(event) {
    console.log('clicked delete');
    event.preventDefault();
    var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));
    if (choice) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit()
    }
});
```